# are Asset thumbnail pre-saved in iOS

Tags: ios, thumbnails, assets

I am writing an app that relays an image saved on the iOS device to a larger screen. Since a fullRes image is too large and takes long to transfer (using an on-device CocoaHTTP server), I am trying to load thumbnail first.

In Windows, we have a thumbs.db, which means that if we access that, there is no image-resizing etc ... its a thumbnail version of the image pre-saved by the OS.

Does the `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.aspectRatioThumbnail]` for the `ALAsset` class in iOS does the same action, or does it load the complete hi-res image and then scales it down before returning?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation does not specify but from my experiments reading the thumbnail is 5 times faster than loading the image from disk (even without decoding or scaling it). I assume iOS stores the pre-made thumbnails somewhere for fast access.